# Generating a number and keeping it until the user does the insert

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Lets say we generate our order numbers in SQL.Normally i get the next number with a

```
SELECT COUNT(numbers)+1 FROM X
```

etc.

The problem is, I want to give this number to the user first,then wait for the user to input the contents, then do the insert to the table.But since there are multiple users i also want them to get the number but not the same number as the first user,is there a way to do this more elegantly?
Shortly i want the number to be reserved to the specific user and insert it if he does,if not, just release the number.

Comment: Why are you not autogenterating numbers? Never generate manually what can be doen faster and moreffectively bythe database.

Comment: At least, if you really really need to generate the numbers manually, don't use `COUNT()+1`. When there are e.g. 3 rows, this will return you 4 as the new number. After deleting #2 you'll end up with 3 rows again, and the new order after it will again be assigned #4. It would be better to use `MAX(numbers)+1` instead.

Comment: Has your question been answered? Or do you require more help?

Comment: Actually we have altered the method completely.cheers tho :)

Answer (score 4):

Create a table of Numbers. Pre-populate the table with values and use this table as [a queue](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/). A transaction can reserve a Number by dequeing a row. On rollback, the number will become again available. Other transactions can concurrently dequeue other numbers due to the readpast semantics of using-a-table-as-queue. Add more numbers (insert more rows) as needed.

If this seems overkill, rest assured: it is not. Naive solutions may not account for concurrency or rollbacks, which are not trivial to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You could insert into the table, and then update it when the user commits their data.

To get around your "releasing" of the numbers you could:
Have a flag on the table to say if the row is "free" or not. When you first insert the flag is "not free". If the user commits their data, keep it as "not free".

If they release their number, mark it as "free".

When assigning a number to a user find the first "free" row, if they aren't any insert a new one.

Answer (score 0):

If you need not to have all numbers sequentially without gaps in your system, you can make simple table containing a column of Identity type. So, insert fake record into it and use `@@IDENTITY` as generated number. This solution of course have some drawbacks as Remus Rusanu mentioned for 'naive solutions'.

If possible, avoid display this number for user before really store it into database. You can generate some abstract number for temporary reference, e.g. from date and time, and after inserting data into database you can display your real number. Almost nothing to code but 100% reliable.

Comment: @@identity can give the wrong identity if someone puts a trigger onteh table, it is far safer to use the OUTPUT clause or scope_Identity()